# Any benefits to storing sql data vertically?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssas

I'm working on several tables that will be eventually be used as a data warehouse for a BI project. These tables store counter data that will then be used to calculate KPIs.

So, for example, the tables currently look like this:

```
DimCounter
Counter       ParmId
KpiStore      1       (used for Sales reports)
KpiInventory  2       (used for Sales reports)
Kpi3          3
Kpi4          4
```

And the data table looks like this:

```
FactSales
ParmId   Value  ProcDate    ProcHour
1        20     20160914    12
2        40     20160914    12
1        70     20160914    12
```

So, right now we have a few Sales reports that are working great with this format; creating the queries with the data in vertical format hasn't been an issue. But I'm thinking that maybe it's better to just store the data horizontally, like so:

```
FactSales
ProcDate    ProcHour    KpiStore    KpiInventory
20160914    12          20          40
```

The Sales reports are really the easier, most straightforward reports since it uses two counters and it's mostly addition/subtraction. But there are others that are far more complex and use many more counters, that need to be grouped several ways.

So is there any benefit in storing the data one way or another? More specifically, is there any benefit of storing data vertically for datawarehousing used for BI?

I forgot to mention that the original source data is stored horizontally (with one metric per column), but the source data is not used for datawarehousing. So the question is essentially if it aids when it comes to datawarehousing.

Thanks.

Comment: Your original vertical structure is clean and extensible.  Just ask yourself what happens when you get a new metric...

Comment: One disadvantage i can see in storing data horizontally is when there is a new `Counter` you may have to alter the table to show the report

Comment: The drawback of the first option is that Value has a fixed type, so you can't change it.

Comment: You seem to be describing an *entity-attribute-value (EAV)* design, its extremely domain specific & subjective as to when this is appropriate, there are many posts on this subject, i.e.  http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20759/is-there-a-name-for-this-database-structure

Answer (score 0):

The biggest benefit to the normalization you currently have in place comes from being able to add new values just by doing a table insert compared to modifying a table structure. On top of that as well you could potentially wind up with a lot of null values for different counter types. For example:

```
FactSales
ProcDate    ProcHour    KpiStore    KpiInventory
20160914    12          20          40
20160915    11          30          NULL
```

This may not be the case with your current data environment but if you were to lock those fields in place then you lose a lot of flexibility. I typically go with more normalization compared to less because I typically want to the potential for more future flexibility of adding new fields and accomodating field changes (sometimes field that used to not allow nulls can sometimes have null in the future) etc...